# SQLite MAX significantly slower than MIN with GROUP BY

Tags: sqlite, group-by

I have several very large databases that I am trying to run some queries on. The table in question has the following (simplified) format, with some sample data. There are additional columns not represented here:

```
uuid | groupId | timestamp
1    |       1 | 01-01-2020 12:30:00
2    |       2 | 01-01-2020 12:30:10
3    |       2 | 01-01-2020 12:30:30
4    |       2 | 01-01-2020 12:30:50
5    |       1 | 01-01-2020 12:31:00
6    |       3 | 01-01-2020 12:32:00
7    |       3 | 01-01-2020 12:34:00
8    |       3 | 01-01-2020 12:35:00
9    |       3 | 01-01-2020 12:36:00
```

I have an index `CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS myindex ON mytable ( groupid, timestamp );`

I want to write a query to return the oldest and newest entries for each groupId. I have come up with the following:

```
SELECT uuid,
       min(timestamp) AS timestamp,
       groupid
FROM mytable
GROUP BY groupid
UNION ALL
SELECT uuid,
       max(timestamp) AS timestamp,
       groupid
FROM mytable
GROUP BY groupid;
```

which returns my desired results. However, the second half with the `max` is significantly slower than the second one, 23 seconds vs 2955 seconds.

When omitting the `uuid` from the select statement, the first half takes 5.7 seconds and the second half takes 10.2. I have considered adding a covering index, but in my actual query I am selecting many more columns and the size of the index would be enormous.

The database I'm running this on is 177GB and the table contains 40 million rows. It's on an NVMe drive.

Running the query on a 48GB database takes 4 seconds for the min half, and 33 for the max half.

How can I either speed up this query or implement a different query to achieve my desired result?

Comment: So what you want is the full rows with max and min timestamp for each groupid?

Comment: That's correct, essentially

Comment: That actually returns what you want? Your timestamp strings aren't in a format that can be meaningfully ordered.

Comment: @SebastienCollier you are right, your code is significantly faster that the code I posted with window functions (this is why I deleted it). I tested a similar case in a large table. Also your code is faster with the composite index that you already have. But I did not find any difference for the execution time between the 2 unioned queries.

Comment: @Shawn Sorry, in my database I have timestamps in the correct format and can be ordered, I've just typed out a simplified example here.

Comment: @forpas I'm only seeing this significant slowdown on databases once they get to 10s or 100s of GB in size